# Empty service call is not executed

Tags: ros, roscpp, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I implemented the basic empty service as proposed by the tutorial in my program:

```
bool callback(std_srvs::Empty::Request& request, std_srvs::Empty::Response& response) {
    return true;
}
```

```
ros::NodeHandle * privateNodeHandle;    
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, node_name);
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    privateNodeHandle = new ros::NodeHandle("~");
    privateNodeHandle->param("publishFrequency", publishFrequency, 1.0);
    privateNodeHandle->param("maximumWaterLevel", maximumWaterLevel, 1.0);  
    ros::Publisher water_level_pub = n.advertise(
            topic, 1000);
    ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("my_service", callback);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(publishFrequency);  
    tank = new WaterTank(maximumWaterLevel);
    int count = 0;
    while (ros::ok()) {
        std_msgs::Float64 msg;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss get_water_level();
        msg.data = tank->get_water_level();
        ROS_INFO("%s", ss.str().c_str());
        water_level_pub.publish(msg);
        loop_rate.sleep();
        ++count;
    }
    delete tank;
    delete privateNodeHandle;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine and I see the service with `rosservice list`. But when I try to call it `rosservice call /my_service` rosservice seems to wait for the service to finish and never returns. This is weird since it is a service with empty parameter and return signature. I also added some debug output to the callback and it seems like it never gets executed. Is there some service blocking part in my main loop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199095/empty-service-call-is-not-executed/) by [odelay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20568/odelay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-08**:
are you able to see your service in `rosservice list` ?

**Comment by [odelay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20568/odelay/) on 2014-12-08**:
Yes it is listed by `rosservice list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is to add a `ros::spinOnce();` to the while loop. It will process all pending callbacks and then return.

---

Originally posted by [odelay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20568/odelay/) with karma: 103 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-08**:
If this works for you please mark the answer as correct.